# How to run drawer code form an action's item?

Tags: flutter

As far as drawer code is intended to run from scaffold and if I use actions then drawer code does not work - is it possible to run drawer code from the action code?

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: age == Type.old ? const Text('Old') : const Text('New'),
    actions: [
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined), onPressed: () {}),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined), onPressed: () {}),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AllCars()),
            );
          }),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {
            // how to run drawer code from here?
        }),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use below method to open drawer of same scaffold

```
Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
```